# How can I find the first and last date in a month

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql

How can I find the first and last date in a month in previous 2 years.For example, today is 07-01-2012(mm-dd-yyyy); I want to find data from 2011 ...
01-01-2011
01-31-2011 
02-01-2011
02-28-2011. Something like that 
Thanks.

Comment: I am pretty confused with your tags.. You have tagged java, php, mysql, sql which is confusing.. can you tell us about where u want this logic to happen ??

Comment: I want to show data month wise, in month we show only first date and last date.Previous year or next year

Comment: This is database related question so if we get logic then we put in java or php

Comment: -1 for not grouping/categorizing your question

Comment: @Rishabh you mean to say that you want all months starting and end dates in the last 2 years?

Comment: You're asking how to find the first date in a month? It's always 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using php date function.

```
$first = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));
$last = date('Y-m-t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year));

$Startyear=2010;
$Endyear=2012;
$monthstart=array();
$monthend=array();
for($i=$Startyear;$i<=$Endyear;$i++){
for($j=1;$j<=12;$j++){
$monthstart[$i][$j]=date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $j, 1, $i));
$monthend[$i][$j]=date('Y-m-t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $j, 1, $i));
}
}
```

Comment: FirstlyThanks,  we want monthlywise data from 07/01/2010 to 07/01/2012. than what should I do?

Comment: @Rishabh : I have added the code above please check it.Hope it will work for u.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select LAST_DAY('2011-01-01') from dual;
```

Comment: I want to show data month wise, in month we show only first date and last date.Previous year or next year

Answer (score 0):

PHP's function `date('t')` can return the amount of days in a month:

```
echo date('t', mktime(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1970));
// outputs 28
```

And secondly, the first day of the month will always be `1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME

SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)),@mydate),101) ,
'Last Day of Previous Month'

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101) AS Date_Value,
'First Day of Current Month' AS Date_Type

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@mydate,101) AS Date_Value, 'Today' AS Date_Type

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),101) ,
'Last Day of Current Month'

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate))-1),DATEADD(mm,1,@mydate)),101) ,
'First Day of Next Month'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the java implementation for the problem you have specified

```
    List<Date> months = new ArrayList<Date>();
    Calendar currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    Calendar today = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    int currentYear = currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) - 2;
    int noOfMonths = 11 - today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    currentDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    currentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear);

    while (currentYear <= today.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {

        for (int monthCount = 0; monthCount <= noOfMonths; monthCount++) {

            currentDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            // adding start date
            months.add(currentDate.getTime());
            // processing end date
            currentDate.set(Calendar.DATE,
                    currentDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
            // adding end date
            months.add(currentDate.getTime());

            // goes to next month
            currentDate.set(Calendar.MONTH,
                    currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        }

        if (currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) == today.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
            if (today.get(Calendar.DATE) != 1) {
                currentDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                // adding start date
                months.add(currentDate.getTime());
            }
            months.add(today.getTime());
            break;
        }
        currentYear++;

        if (currentYear == today.get(Calendar.YEAR)) {
            noOfMonths = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) - 1;
        } else {
            noOfMonths = 11;
        }
        currentDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, currentYear);

    }

    for (Date date : months) {
        System.out.println(format.format(date));
    }
```

This program prints all the month start and end dates in the previous 2 years from today. The last date would be the current day!

Answer (score 0):

My Algorithm would be to find the number of days in the month.  Based on that I can find the first and last day.
To find the number of days in a month we can use Fist Rule.
Only for the month of Feb we have to check for leap year

31 days month
(month seq no  > 7 ) ?(month seq no + 1)%2 : (month seq no) % 2.
If the result for above equation is true then it is 31 days month, else 30days month.
Only for the month seqno 2 (Feb) we have to consider the Leap year Calculation.